# Time-dependent perturbation - details in derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian-formalism, perturbation-theory

I get confused about two things when deriving the time-dependent [perturbative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29) approach.

We have the Hamiltonian
$$H = H_0 + \lambda H^{(1)}$$
and we have solved (from Schroedinger)
$$\dot{C_f(t)} = - \frac{i}{\hbar}\sum_{k}\lambda C_k(t)H^{(1)}_{f,k}e^{i\omega_{f,k}t} $$
with the usual
$H^{(1)}_{f,k} = <f|H^{(1)_{f,k}}|i> $ and  $\omega_{f,k} = \frac{E_f-E_i}{\hbar}$.

Ok. Next I expand $$C_k(t) = C^{(0)}_k(t) + C^{(1)}_k(t)\lambda + C^{(2)}_k(t)\lambda^2 +...$$
Substituting that I get
$$\frac{d}{dt}(C^{(0)}_k(t) + C^{(1)}_k(t)\lambda + C^{(2)}_k(t)\lambda^2 +... )= - \frac{i}{\hbar}\sum_{k}\lambda (C^{(0)}_k(t) + C^{(1)}_k(t)\lambda + C^{(2)}_k(t)\lambda^2 +...)H^{(1)}_{f,k}e^{i\omega_{f,k}t} $$

From this I am unable to see
**1) Why does the zeroth order correspond to $\lambda = 0$?**
To me this would feel like we have a situation where we have a variable, and for some reason we would be allowed to choose its value for the first term of the series? [As, it stays as a coefficient in the right side of the previous equation]
2) Ok, then if I set $\dot{C}^{(0)}_k = 0$ then I get the recursion relation
$$\dot{C}^{(n)}_f(t) = - \frac{i}{\hbar}\sum_{k} C^{(n-1)}_k(t)H^{(1)}_{f,k}e^{i\omega_{f,k}t} $$ 
**Did we substitute $\lambda = 1$ in the last**, or what happened to lambda if not? (This is not stated in the sources that I try to study, but it's the only explanation I come up with right now)

Comment: The zeroth order is simply the result of the unperturbed Hamiltonian. In that case, you can kill the perturbation potential by setting $\lambda = 0$. Remember: you're matching powers of $\lambda$ and not values of $\lambda$ when doing perturbation theory.

Comment: Hmm, but $\lambda^0=1$, not $0$?

Comment: Zeroth order is usually a term assigned to the unperturbed Hamiltonian. Think of what you just did -- by saying $\lambda^0 = 1$, you are arguing that the Hamiltonian you are solving is $H_0 + H_1$ to zeroth order, $H_0 + \lambda H_1$ to first order, $H_0 + \lambda^2 H_1$ to second order and so on for a small parameter $\lambda$. That misses the entire point of using $\lambda$ as a perturbative "knob" that you turn on to see the corrections to the zeroth order eigenstates and eigenenergies.

Comment: Yes, I see. Mathematically rather unsatisfactory though, especially since your (eqb) argument is not generally stated in textbooks or articles. Fishy. 
Also am I correct guessing the answer to my second question? At that point, lambda=1 is substituted back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations hold due to the non-trivial property of the uniqueness of the Taylor expansion. Consider the left and right hand side of an equation as a function,
\begin{equation}
f(\lambda)=g(\lambda)
\end{equation}
Now Taylor expand both sides,
\begin{equation}
f_0 + \lambda f_1 + \lambda^2 f_2^2 +  ... =g _0 + \lambda g _1+ \lambda^2g _2^2 +....
\end{equation}
Since the Taylor expansion is unique "both ways" of Taylor expanding are equivalent and we must have 
\begin{equation}
f_i = g_i 
\end{equation}
for all $i$.

Intuitively you can understand the statement as follows. The equation must hold at all $\lambda$ so it must hold at $\lambda=0 \Rightarrow f_0=g_0$. Now suppose that you increase $\lambda$ a tiny bit. In this case all the $\lambda^2,\lambda^3, ... $ terms are going to be very small. At this point we have,
\begin{equation}
\lambda f_1\approx \lambda g_1
\end{equation}
So we must have $f_1=g _1$ (since we can make $\lambda$ arbitrarily small). You can continue the process iteratively to show that you can equate coefficients of a Taylor expansion to all orders.

Comment: Thanks. By remembering the uniqueness of series I was able to understand the recursion relation. 
But a good point: we are expanding around lambda=0, that explains the zeroth order